# A synonym for 'rich' (varied) without connotations of wealth

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you refer to someone who has access to an abundance of resources?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59974/how-do-you-refer-to-someone-who-has-access-to-an-abundance-of-resources)

Is there a [synonym for rich](http://thesaurus.com/browse/rich) that does not have the connotation of wealth? I am looking for something closer to 'has many resources' or 'has much content'. For example:

> The FOSS community is rich enough that one need not pay for an office suite. One can choose from any of the free office suits available.

Another example:

> My aunt (who receives welfare) has a house rich enough in tapestries that she does not need to buy tapestries.

The sentences provided are *examples* of the usage of the word 'rich' in the sense that I mean. There is no need to dispute FOSS office suites or whether we need one.

Thanks.

Comment: How would that be appropriate when you are talking about _paying_ for something?

Comment: The implication is that one could acquire an office suite for free, without paying.

Comment: Thank you jwpat! I'm divided as to whether or not this is a dupe. If it is I'll happily mark it as such, let me go over that one a bit more. Thanks!

Comment: How does *fruitful* strike you?

Comment: I see that the question has received two downvotes. Downvoters, please mention what can be improved. Thanks.

Comment: @dotancohen: I didn't downvote this question, but I can take a stab at why it got downvoted. As soon as I read: "Is there a synonym for..." I think, "thesaurus." You provided a link to a thesaurus (which was good, it shows you at least looked), but you never explained why you couldn't find your answer there.  Remember, though, that's not my downvote, so I'm only making a guess.

Comment: @Cameron: Fruitfull strikes me as something that bears fruit, not something that possesses fruit.

Comment: +1 for checking the thesaurus before posting. Question covers the same content as an earlier question: voting to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of all the synonym families for *rich*, the words that I think fit most closely to your purposes are the words under *abundant*:

[image]

One word that I might recommend isn't listed there, though; I think the word ***replete*** might work.  NOAD says:

> **replete** (adj.): 
>   filled or well-supplied with something

Moreover, [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/replete) defines replete as *copiously supplied with*. So, one might say:

> My aunt's house is replete enough in tapestries that she does not need to buy any more.

or:

> The FOSS community is replete with office space. As a matter of fact, you don't even need to rent an office, there’s an abundance of free office suites available.

If you want to use something informal, I think the synonym *crawling with* makes for some interesting language:

> The FOSS community is crawling with office space.

NOAD says that *crawling with* means *to be covered or crowded with insects or people, to an extent that is disgusting or objectionable*, while Collins reads: *to be or feel as if overrun by something unpleasant, esp crawling creatures*.  So, applying that phrase to a hypersufficiency of office space might be somewhat metaphoric, and the phrase *crawling with* might be more fitting if the overabundance of office space or tapestries was viewed as a bad thing.  I might use those words in conversation, but I'd probably avoid it in more formal writing.

By the way, ***overabundant*** might be a good word, too; from [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overabundance):

> **overabundance** (n.): a supply or amount that is greater than required
>   **overabundant** (adj.): too abundant; excessive

So, one could say:

> There is an overabundance of office space in the FOSS community, and my aunt's house is overabundant in tapestries. (That's why she never stops by the tapestry store on her way home from her freely-rented office space.)

Comment: Thank you, "replete" seems the appropriate word. This is a terrific, detailed response!

Answer (score 1):

*Rich* is fine; or maybe use the common phrase *rich and varied*. If a **thing** is 
rich rather than a person, there is little possibility of any connotation of monetary wealth.

The problem is the word *community*. I think you are saying that there is so much free open-source software available that you should never have to buy something like Microsoft Office; but your sentence would make *community* mean **that software** rather than **the people who write it.**

> The FOSS community's offering is so rich and varied that one need not pay for an office suite.

Now that the question has been clarified, note the use of ***so*** in that sentence, rather than *enough*. You want to emphasise *abundance* rather than *mere sufficiency*.

> My aunt (who is on welfare) has a house so rich in tapestries that she does not need to buy any.

Comment: The office suite was just an example, I have added an additional example. While informative, you are addressing the wrong part of the example sentence!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the importance of `so`. I now see where that makes the distinction.